# Laravel Voyager redirect to other page after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I just started using Laravel and learning. I would like to redirect users to a custom section create through the BREAD.

In Voyager Controller, I see there is this function return Voyager::view('voyager::index');
I want to redirect to the page /admin/members
How can I achieve this? I tried to search around but can't find the solution. Hope someone can help with this. Thank you

Comment: change this line https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.2/src/Http/Controllers/VoyagerAuthController.php#L54

Comment: @STA Thanks for your reply, I tried this, but the page I wanted to redirect to is a new module. /admin/members is created via BREAD. If I put voyager.members I will get Route [voyager.members] not defined

Comment: Then there are no route named `voyager.members` would you give me the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @STA Thank you for trying to help ! I really appreciate it. Here's the output.
 
POST      | admin/members  | voyager.members.store   
 | App\Http\Controllers\Voyager\MemberController@store  
                   
 GET|HEAD  | admin/members  | voyager.members.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Voyager\MemberController@index

Comment: Change this line `return Voyager::view('voyager::index'); ` to `return redirect()->route('voyager.members.index');` hope this helps?

Comment: @STA thank you for trying to help! I have changed but I get this error 
Route [voyager.members] not defined.

Comment: Are you sure its `voyager.members.index`?  Not `voyager.members`

Comment: @STA I tried removing the "index", and just voyager.members . I still get the same error Route [voyager.members] not defined. :(

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by updating the user's configuration in config/voyager.php (Laravel config directory). Edit below configurations (redirect index)

```
'user' => [
    'add_default_role_on_register' => true,
    'default_role'                 => 'user',
    'default_avatar'               => 'users/default.png',
    'redirect'                     => '/admin',
],
```

to

```
'user' => [
    'add_default_role_on_register' => true,
    'default_role'                 => 'user',
    'default_avatar'               => 'users/default.png',
    'redirect'                     => '/admin/members',
],
```